# Select paragraph of selected word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the surrounding paragraph of a word which is selected by the user in the browser. Is this possible?

I currently have:

```
// returns a trimmed version of the currently selected text
function getTrimmedSelection() {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var words = String(selection);
    var context = getSelectedParagraphText(selection);
    console.log("CONTEXT: " + context)
}

function getSelectedParagraphText(selection) {
    var parent = selection.anchorNode;
    while (parent != null && parent.localName != "P") {
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }

    if (parent == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return parent.innerText || parent.textContent;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in IE and Chrome, `localName` returns a lower-case value, and since string comparison in JavaScript is case-sensitive, your `parent.localName != "P"` condition is always true and you never exit the loop. For safety, you might want to do a case-insensitive comparison:

```
while (parent != null && parent.localName.toLowerCase() != "p") {
  parent = parent.parentNode;
}
```

Here's a fiddle with it working: https://jsfiddle.net/gnyfdtof/1/